# The function of « de là » in the phrase « regarder de là où vous êtes »

Tags: grammaire

> 1 : Ça risque d'être dangereux si vous approchez. Vous pourriez **regarder de là où** vous êtes ?

Obviously, this sentence is an equivalent of:

« Vous pourriez regarder où vous mettez les pieds ? »

But how does it compare with:

> 2 : Vous pourriez **regarder là où** vous êtes ?
>
> 3 : Vous pourriez **regarder où** vous êtes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1 : Ça risque d'être dangereux si vous approchez. Vous pourriez regarder de là où vous êtes ?
>
> Obviously, this sentence is an equivalent of:
>
> « Vous pourriez regarder où vous mettez les pieds ? »

It's not and thence your problem.

It could be rephrased as "Vous pourriez regarder de **l'endroit** où vous êtes" or translated "You could look from where you're standing.

*Là où* here functions as an antecedentless relative pronoun, the locative equivalent of *ce que*, *ce qui*, *ce dont*, etc. *De* is simply a preposition indicating the origin of an action (here, *regarder*)

Comment: Ok for the first remark but it seems strange to analyze *là où* the way you do. How would you analyze *l'endroit où* then? It would be easier to analyze *là* as the complement of the preposition *de* and the antecedent of the relative *où* in a way parallel to the other example. The sentence could be shortened to *Vous pourriez regarder de là.* where it seems obvious that *là* is completely independent from *où* and acts as the complement of *de*. The same hold for the constructions in *ce* where *ce* is the antecendent pronoun for the usual relatives alternating with *ça* in absolute contexts